# Elegant way to transform Multi-thread into Single-thread

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety

1.
I have main UI thread and it uses library functions.

```
MainUI {
    library.funcA(1);
    library.funcB(2,3);
}
```

I don't want Main-Thread to wait for the end of each call. Also creating new thread for each call is ineffective and not thread-safe so I want them to run on another same thread.
So I created another thread with a single message queue / handler.

```
MainUI {
    handler.post(new Message(FUNC_A,[1]));
    handler.post(new Message(FUNC_B,[2,3]));
}
```

but it seems having overhead that I need to create new Message object every time and decode it again in handleMessage(). Furthermore It looks ugly to handle the various number of arguments packing/unpacking. I thought making all functions as Runnable and post them to handler, but functions have different arguments and I need to make new classes extending Runnable class!

my current plan is to insert synchronized keywords into every function in library so threads run one by one,
but I dislike many threads creating/disappering so making system heavy (also not thread-safe). I want to hear opinions.

2.
if the library is called from many threads (not only Main-thread), what's the best way to convert calls to run on the library's own single thread?

Comment: no, working on View.java in android framework. It calls my function for every touch on view. I should interrupt as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your current approach is feasible option to make thread-safe. However, if you want to go for having Runnable passed to handler, you could consider overloading your Runnable class. Here is pseudo-code

```
private Class MyRunner extends Runnable{
    public MyRunner(){
    //This is without any argument
    }

    public MyRunner(arg1){
    //This is with 1 argument
    }

    public MyRunner(arg1,arg2){
    //This is with 2 arguments
    }

}
```

Still, you will have many instances of MyRunner class created.

Comment: 1. Runnable is interface 2. Handler would call MyRunner.run(), so how can you dynamically change the action of run() method from MyRunner constructors?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Runnable like this:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
//  "a" and "b" are here to show how variable values can be sent to funcB.
//  You could skip this and just have "funcB( 1, 2 )", of course.
final int  a = x;  
final int  b = y;
handler.post( new Runnable()  {
    public void run()  { library.funcB( a, b ); }
} );
```

The handler bit is a bit trickier.  It has to run a looping thread to run each Runnable from the queue.  Then it has to have a `post` method to put things on the queue.  Some form of blocking queue would be the simplest way to link the two, saving you from having to do your own Object.wait/Object.notify.  Synchronizing the `post` method would be the easiest way to keep multiple threads from tripping over each other.